# Laravel Homestead - older versions of PHP and Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4, vagrant

Is it possible to run homestead with an older version of PHP and Laravel 4.1?  I need to set up my VM to replicate our production server, as closely as possible.

Comment: I'm wrong. 4.1 can still run on php 5.3.7+. 4.2 requires 5.4.x.+.

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I missed your previous comment, I'm assuming therefore that you can?  How is this set up?

Comment: I don't know about getting a prepacked version of homestead with laravel 4.1 and php 5.3. I think you'd need to do it manually.

Answer (score 1):

I find myself in 2021. According to the [official docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/homestead#php-versions) and with the current Laravel homestead v10.17.0 you have the possibility to explicitly set the PHP version required right at the `Homestead.yml` file:

```
sites:
    - map: homestead.test
      to: /home/vagrant/project1/public
      php: "7.1"
    - map: project2.test
      to: /home/vagrant/project2/public
      php: "5.6"
    - map: default.test
      to: /home/vagrant/project1/public
```

Then, don't forget to apply the changes with

```
% vagrant provision
```

Moreover, you could change dynamically the PHP version used in your Laravel Homestead Ubuntu virtual machine

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config PHP
$ php -i | grep "Loaded Configuration File"
$ php -v
```

But that only works for composer update, it doesn't seem to work for an application. So changing the `Homestead.yml` file is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Homestead is just a prepackaged version of Vagrant with PHP5.6, ngnix, mySQL  etc already installed and configurable.

If you need a specific environment that is "different" to Homestead, you just create your own Vagrant environment with a bashscript that installs the versions of software that closely matches your production environment.

[This guide here provides specific information for Laravel](http://culttt.com/2013/06/17/setting-up-vagrant-with-laravel-4/) - but any Vagrant guide will be able to help.